# error: method contains in class String cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, string

this statement shows  this error: method contains in class String cannot be applied to given types;

```
boolean m=str[j].contains(a);
```

why this happens and what is the remedy.It would be great if someone helps.. thank you..

Comment: what is the datatype of `str[j]`

Comment: What is the datatype of `a`?

Comment: @JigarJoshi It's of type String. The more important question is what is the type of 'a'.

Comment: Obviously `a` is not instanceof `CharSequence`.

Comment: a is of Character datatype...what is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 3):

Since the method `contains()` need to receive a `CharSequence`, probably your variable `a` is not an instance of `CharSequence`.

So, do a validation:

```
if(a instanceof CharSequence ){
    boolean m=str[0].contains(a); 
}
```

---- Edit
Try this:

```
CharSequence a = 'a'.toString();
boolean m = str[0].contains(a);
```

Comment: actually a is of the type Character.. What is the diff. between a Character sequence and a Character..

Comment: The name says everything, i'm going to edit my post to try to help you out

Answer (score 1):

When you say `str[j]`, you are subscripting it, so `str[j]` is a `char`. And `contains()` method cannot be applied on `char`. What you want to do is probably this :

```
String str = "StackOverflow";
boolean isOPresent = str.contains('O');
System.out.println(isOPresent); // will print true
```

Comment: what is the type of `a` then?

Answer (score 0):

Without the code that surrounds this statement it will be difficult to tell exactly what's wrong. But from that one line, my guess is that either the variable a is not of type char or str is not a string but rather a char as well. Post more code and maybe we can help more thoroughly

UPDATE:
The variable that is sent in to the 'contains' function must be of type CharSequence according to the Java Docs.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html

Comment: The error he posted says the 'method contains in class String cannot be applied to given types'. Which means str[ j ] has to be of type String. So the problem is whatever type is 'a'.

Comment: according to the java docs, contains needs a charSequence to work.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: And there is the error. 'a' is not of type CharSequence.

Comment: So there's his answer.

Comment: 'a' is of Character.. is there any difference between CharSequence and Character?? what is tht

Comment: yes. It looks like charSequence is an interface. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html